# How to automatically install Ansible Galaxy roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

All my Ansible playbooks/roles are checked in to my git repo.

However, for Ansible Galaxy roles I always have to explicitly download them one by one on every machine I want to run Ansible from.

It's even tough to know in advance exactly which Ansible Galaxy roles are needed until Ansible complains about a missing role at runtime.

How is one supposed to manage the Ansible Galaxy role dependencies? I would like to either have them checked into my git repo along with the rest of my ansible code or have them automatically be identified and downloaded when I run Ansible on a new machine.

Comment: https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/index.html Here is everythings you need to use ansible-galaxy.
It's a well done doc ! Even if you are beginner :)

Comment: @pdeva Could you accept one of the valid answer below?

Answer (score 186):

You should use a `requirements.yml` file for this use-case. Describe the roles you require, using any of a variety of install methods:

```
# Install a role from the Ansible Galaxy
- src: dfarrell07.opendaylight

# Install a role from GitHub
- name: opendaylight
  src: https://github.com/dfarrell07/ansible-opendaylight

# Install a role from a specific git branch
- name: opendaylight
  src: https://github.com/dfarrell07/ansible-opendaylight
  version: origin/master

# Install a role at a specific tag from GitHub
- name: opendaylight
  src: https://github.com/dfarrell07/ansible-opendaylight
  version: 1.0.0

# Install a role at a specific commit from GitHub
- name: opendaylight
  src: https://github.com/dfarrell07/ansible-opendaylight
  version: <commit hash>
```

Then install them:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

Here's a [working example](https://github.com/dfarrell07/vagrant-opendaylight/blob/master/requirements.yml) (installing OpenDaylight using Ansible as a Vagrant provisioner). See the [relevant Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/galaxy.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file) for more info.

Comment: See also @Kieran Andrews answer below. It expands this one.

Comment: This isn't really automatically installing the role dependencies of a playbook, it's explicitly installing a list of dependencies that have been manually listed by the human who made the playbook.

Answer (score 56):

As suggested, you can use ansible galaxy for this need.

Ansible has a feature where you can create a `requirements.yml` file that lists all of your roles. You can find out about that here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file

For example (requirements.yml):

```
- src: yatesr.timezone
```

You then run `ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` on this file to download all of the roles listed there.

If you would like to further automate it then, you can create a simple shell script that will run the two commands.

For example (ansible.sh):

`./ansible.sh`

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory
```

Comment: Just tested, It displays a message that roles are already downloaded, no error. Version `2.2.1`

Comment: If the playbook makes use of the galaxy roles that you're installing then they won't run the first time the playbook is invoked as their presence is checked before they have been downloaded.  Calling the playbook a second time will then pick up the newly-installed roles.

Comment: I have updated to how I have now been doing it, with a wrapper script to reduce commands.

Answer (score 20):

I often find myself installing installing a Java JDK. Using a role makes that touch easier. I've tried a couple of different ways (including lots of .gitmodules and submodule... I have to use multiple git systems for work and all it gets ugly). My largest requirement is that I not check role code into my playbook project, mostly so I can keep everything in one place.

The contents of my 'requirements.yml' file:

```
- src: https://github.com/staylorx/ansible-role-wls-prep.git
  version: master
  name: staylorx.wls-prep

- src: https://my-work-git-extravaganza.com
  version: 2.x
  name: coolplace.niftyrole

#From Ansible Galaxy
- src: staylorx.oracle-jdk
```

I run a separate playbook, install-roles.yml:

```
---

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - file:
        path:  roles
        state: absent

    - local_action:
        command ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml --roles-path roles

    - lineinfile:
        dest:   .gitignore
        regexp: '^\/roles$'
        line:   '/roles'
        state:  present
```

I run this first playbook, then I run my roles in any playbook normally. For me the secret is to ensure it's ignored by git so I don't check the roles in by mistake. Also since I wipe out the folder every time, I ensure I don't need to force or ignore errors.

Comment: It'll fail with 'role not found' before you even run the local command.

Comment: @Mincă Daniel Andrei you need use dynamic way, ex include_role. check [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html)

Answer (score 13):

You could use an Ansible role to install the needed roles using the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html).

Here is a very basic example that runs [`ansible-galaxy install`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#installing-roles):

```
- name: Install roles from Ansible Galaxy
  command: ansible-galaxy install {{ item.item }}
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_roles_list }}"
```

The `ansible_roles_list` may be supplied as a variable or as a role parameter.

If you do this in a role, it has to be applied **before** any other roles that you want to install using it, in a separate playbook. This is because Ansible checks the if all the roles are available before running the playbook where you reference them.

Comment: egg and chicken :)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use git submodules. After all, Ansible Galaxy only is a directory of github repositories...

I use this command to automatically add any Galaxy role as a submodule:

```
ansible-galaxy info <package> | grep -A 1 github_repo | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e "s/.*github_repo: \([^[:space:]]*\)[^\w]*github_user: \([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*/git submodule add git:\/\/github.com\/\2\/\1.git roles\/\2.\1/g" | sh
```

Commit the changes then to your git repo. When you clone your repo in future make sure to clone it with submodules, e.g. `git clone ... --recursive`

An advantage of this is, a git submodule is always referencing a specific version (git commit-hash). This will prevent you from running untested updates in your productive environment. A new version of a Galaxy role could have bugs or work completely different than before. With a git submodule you decide if and when you update a role to the new version.

Also, you won't have to additionally take care of blacklisting galaxy roles in your `.gitignore` to prevent committing their code to your repository.

Comment: This is bad practice in my opinion. It's usually simpler to use dependency management tools then to glue SCM repos together, especially when we're talking about git submodules for SCM.

Comment: Agreed. In fact I'm not using this any longer. Still it is a valid approach since ansible-galaxy is far from perfect. Galaxy won't check for updates, even if a version is bumped in your requirements file, if you force it to re-download all roles with the undocumented `--force` flag it won't show you if or what actually changed. It's a black box you only can control if you keep the downloaded galaxy roles in SCM. For other reasons that's a good idea anyway though. When pulling submodules you at least see which roles changed.

Comment: BTW, all the problems submodules have, AFAIK are negligible in this situation because they are related to modifying their content. Pulling is perfectly fine by my experience..

Answer (score 3):

At this point in time, as far as I know there's no automatic way to download roles at runtime.
Your best bet is to either commit them into your own repo or have a proper documentation listing all the requirements.
You could even create a pre-flight playbook that installs your roles. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here, my requirements are on the role and used in install.yml

main.yml

```
 # tasks file for MY_ROLE
- name: Install requirements
  local_action: command ansible-galaxy install -r {{ role_path }}/requirements.yml -p /etc/ansible/roles

- include_tasks: install.yml
```

```
.  
├── playbook.yml  
├── inventory  
├── roles  
│    └── My_Role   
│        ├── tasks  
│        │   └── main.yml  
│        │   └── install.yml  
│        └── requirements.yml
```

Comment: A simplified version if you only want to install the requirements:
```
- name: Install ansible galaxy requirements
  local_action: command ansible-galaxy install -r {{ role_path }}/requirements.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: you can't. At best you can add a separate role to do the installs, but it will still fail if you try to include a Galaxy role in your playbook. So there's simply no other way than to install it manually. Yes, it is ridiculous, like many other things in Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Exaple HowTo install a Ansible Galaxy role in playbook:

```
- name: Install role from Ansible Galaxy
  local_action: command /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy install <GALAXY_PACKAGE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to automatically download a playbook's needed roles. As others have suggested, using a `requirements.yml` file is one way, and maybe the best way, to do this.

However, you can also use a role's `meta/main.yml` file to specify it's dependencies. See the [Roles documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies) page. You can use this syntax for if you're using a private repo for example.

```yaml
dependencies:
   - name: java
     src: ssh://git@myServer/myWorkspace/myRole.git
     scm: git
     version: master
```

So you can define a `requirements.yml` file to download `myRole`, and then it will download any roles it needs, and they can in turn download any roles they need through their `meta/main.yml` files. This is a lot more work that having a `requirements.yml` file IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@staylorx answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35319216/11379030), you can create a pre-task like so:

```yaml
- name: Install requirements
  delegate_to: localhost
  ansible.builtin.command: ansible-galaxy install -r {{ role_path }}/requirements.yml
```

that points to your [requirements.yml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#install-multiple-collections-with-a-requirements-file)

For example, your playbook will probably look like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Deploy
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  # ...

  collections:
    # All the collections you'll need

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install requirements
      delegate_to: localhost
      ansible.builtin.command: ansible-galaxy install -r {{ role_path }}/requirements.yml
    # Other tasks that you run BEFORE the roles

  roles:
    - { role: "roleX", tags: "roleX" }
    # your other roles

  post_tasks:
    # other tasks that you run AFTER the roles
```

Refs:

- [delegate_to docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

Answer (score 0):

If requirements.yml resides in the roles directory of your project, then Tower/AWX installs the roles automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your gitlab account create a group where you put all your roles
2. Go to settings/repository and add a token with read rights
3. Copy the token-name:token an paste it in a requirements.yml file

```yaml
- src: 'https://<token-name>:<token>@gitlab.com/ansible-cim/roles/instnginx.git'
  scm: 'git'
  version: 'v0.0.1'
  name: 'instnginx'
```

6. Edit ansible.cfg if necessary to indicate where roles will be installed

```
[defaults]
roles_path=./roles
```

7. Create folder ./roles if necessery
8. Launch ansible-galaxy command

```sh
mkdir roles
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

Comment: You don't want such a token in a repository, since it's sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

I use Crono's method in AWX but also on my local ansible controller.

It works well but somehow messes with the path where roles are eventually downloaded to.

My Git project is called 'roles' and I add it to requirements.yml:

```
- src: "git+https://<token_name>:<token>@gitlab.mydomain.com/mygroup/ansible/roles.git"
```

When I run

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

I get this folder structure in my roles directory after sync:

```
├── roles  
│  └── roles
│       └── My_Role   
│            ├── tasks  
│            │   └── main.yml
```

This forces me to include my roles like this in the playbook:

```
  hosts: [all]
  roles:
    - roles/roles/My_Role
```

Is there any way to sync the roles from git without the root folder??
You can do this with git via:

```
git clone "https://<token_name>:<token>@gitlab.mydomain.com/mygroup/ansible/roles.git ."
```

but the dot convention does not work inside the `requirements.yml` file.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: To answer my own question:
1. It is better to have one ansible role per one Git project - for multiple reasons: first, downloading via ansible-galaxy then puts in in the correct roles folder without issues. Second, in case of changes, other branches, etc. it is just more convenient to separate from other roles. Third, access control can be granted more granularly.

Comment: 2. Role collections can be synchronized from a single Git project, but the top level folder of the Git project must contain a /meta/main.yml folder/file. An accidental "feature" in Galaxy will treat it as one role during deployment. This will prevent the "double-folder" creation.