# How to specify dependecies to Ansible Galaxy roles from other roles?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've specified dependency for my role by declaring it inside `meta/main.yml`.

```
---
dependencies:
  - role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu
    src: https://github.com/angstwad/docker.ubuntu
    scm: git
    version: v2.3.0
```

However when I try to execute Ansible playbook I'm seeing error message:

```
ERROR! the role 'angstwad.docker_ubuntu' was not found in /home/.../ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/.../ansible/roles:/home/.../ansible

The error appears to have been in '/home/.../roles/docker-node/meta/main.yml': line 5, column 5, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - role: angstwad.docker_ubuntu
    ^ here
```

From the error message I conclude that external role `angstwad.docker_ubuntu` hasn't be imported, even if it has been explicitly mentioned in `docker-node/meta/main.yml`.

---

Can I specify external dependencies from Ansible Galaxy even if my role itself has not been uploaded to Ansible Galaxy?

Or do I need to explicitly import them using `ansible-galaxy`?

---

From Ansible [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html):

> Roles can also be dependent on other roles, and when you install a
>   role that has dependencies, those dependenices will automatically be
>   installed.
>
> You specify role dependencies in the meta/main.yml file by providing a
>   list of roles. If the source of a role is Galaxy, you can simply
>   specify the role in the format username.role_name. The more complex
>   format used in requirements.yml is also supported, allowing you to
>   provide src, scm, version and name.

By following suggestions from another SO question ([How to automatically install Ansible Galaxy roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230376/how-to-automatically-install-ansible-galaxy-roles)) it sounds like downloading external dependencies needs to be done explicitly either manually or with workaround.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Are you sure the error message does not start with `ERROR! the role 'angstwad.docker_ubuntu' was not found in`? Basically it seems to me as if you had already answered your own question.

Comment: @techraf Yes Ansible is unable to locate an external role, even though I've specified it in `meta/main.yml`. But shouldn't it try to download it based on given specifiers? This isn't clear to me.

Comment: If "*yes*" -- it means you still have not included the error message. "*when you install a role*" -- did you install the role?

Answer (score 2):

If the role that has this dependency is itself being installed via ansible-galaxy, then revise `meta/main.yml` to look like this:

```yaml
---
dependencies:
  - src: https://github.com/angstwad/docker.ubuntu.git
    scm: git
    version: v2.3.0
```

Thus, when installing the primary role the docker.ubuntu role will automatically be installed in `~/.ansible/roles/docker.ubuntu` and it will run when the playbook is executed.

If the role that has this dependency will NOT be installed via ansible-galaxy, that is, if the dependency is the only thing being installed via the ansible-galaxy command, then docker.ubuntu will have to be installed separately, e.g.

```
ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/angstwad/docker.ubuntu.git
```

or

```
ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/angstwad/docker.ubuntu.git -p /path_to/my_playbook/roles
```

This will place the role in your search path (again, `~/.ansible/roles/docker.ubuntu` if not specified via `-p`). In this scenario, revise `meta/main.yml` to this:

```yaml
---
dependencies:
  - role: docker.ubuntu
```

Note that when pulling your role from github, it lands as `docker.ubuntu` vs `docker_ubuntu`. See https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html#dependencies for more. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation you linked](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#dependencies), you see:

> When dependencies are encountered by `ansible-galaxy`, it will automatically install each dependency to the roles_path.

Downloading of dependencies is handled by ansible-galaxy only, the src meta information doesn't affect ansible-playbook, which just looks inside your role directory and if it don't see a corresponding folder - it fails. As in [answer in question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230376/how-to-automatically-install-ansible-galaxy-roles/34667069#34667069), you can indeed create a first task, or include in you playbook to run ansible galaxy before each start.

Comment: I wonder what is the use of `src` in `meta/main.yml` file? Is there any? I find it very misleading.