# How to create ansible galaxy roles in windows?

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-galaxy

I am learning ansible from ansible-beginner to pro by micheal heap. It seems that ansible is not supported on windows. The book suggests running ansible from a virtual machine instead. I started a VMbox using vagrant, which has ubuntu/trusty64 on it. I am successfully able to run my playbooks on it. However, I ran into an issue when creating ansible-galaxy roles.

I could not find a way to create/ initialize a role on windows. I vaguely borrowed ideas from this question [How to automatically install Ansible Galaxy roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230376/how-to-automatically-install-ansible-galaxy-roles) and added the following command to my playbook create roles on windows 
`local_action: command ansible-galaxy init sush.util --init-path roles`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: make sure we can connect
      ping:
    #ansible-galaxy
    - name: Init sush.util
      local_action: command ansible-galaxy init sush.util --init-path roles
      ignore_errors: true
```

I also added `ignore_errors=true` to ignore the errors if the role has already been created. 
Is this the correct approach or is there another/better to do this in windows ?

Comment: Yeah, probably the code does not make it clear the objective. I want to create an empty role structure, then I go and add tasks to main.yml files inside the empty roles and then I plan to use the role.
I have ubuntu OS on VMBox, not on my computer. I plan to install wordpress, nginx, php etc on the VM. I want to create roles in a folder on windows for each and reuse them each time I want a component installed.

Comment: Just do it. I don't see a point in employing Ansible for what people usually use `vi` or their other favourite editor.

Comment: Kindly, explain your answer. I don't understand anything of what you said. How would you create ansible-galaxy role without using ansible ?
The purpose here is to learn ansible, not install wordpress.
I asked how to create an empty ansible galaxy role on windows ?
If you don't know the answer, please don't post useless irrelevant comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your aim is to create a role locally on Windows, you don't actually need to use Ansible Galaxy to do that. An Ansible role is just a set of folders. To create a `sush.util` role, create a folder named `sush.util` and then create the following folders inside that:

- tasks
- handlers
- templates
- files
- vars
- meta

Finally, inside each of these folders create a file named `main.yml` that contains `---` at the top.

You now have an Ansible role that you can run. Any tasks you add to `tasks/main.yml` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually do : Just create those folders and main.yml file

```
*$path = "c:\git\install-sqlserver"
$main = "main.yml"
$dir = "defaults","files","handlers","meta","tasks","templates","tests","vars"
foreach ($d in $Dir){
New-Item -Path $path -Name $d -ItemType "directory"
New-Item -Path "$path\$d" -Name $main -ItemType "file" -Value "---"
if ((Test-path $path )){
New-Item -Path $path -Name $main -ItemType "file" -Value "---" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } 
}*
```