# How do I create an Ansible Base Role locally?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Ansible roles for a common sensible base configuration for all machines. Should support RHEL/Debian/SuSE/Solaris/HPUX/Ubuntu Linux.

The Base host configuration should perform the following tasks:

- ntp – configure NTP settings based on common configuration
- ssh – configure SSH security, service, key settings
- Package Yum / repo – configure Operating System native package manager to operate against internal HPE resources and/or externally-available resources (like ftp.debian.org).

I am new to creating Ansible Roles. I haven't tried anything yet, looking for guidance.

```
- name: restart ntp
  service:
    name: ntp
    state: restarted
- name: restart sshd
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```

Comment: It's pretty well documented in ansibles documentation how to write a role.
https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/finding/content_types.html#ansible-roles

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you have questions, please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you Vladimir

Comment: @Keith: StackOverflow is kind of specific in how to comment. With all respect, please have a look at the Help Center:  [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Some details are also available in accepted and upvoted SO question [How to create ansible galaxy roles in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781461/how-to-create-ansible-galaxy-roles-in-windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create your own role start with

```
$ ansible-galaxy init test
```

This "creates the skeleton framework of a role that complies with the galaxy metadata format"

```
> tree test
test
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

For details see [Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html).

There is plenty of roles shared at [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) that you might want to search in the browser, or from the command line. For example roles with tags: Solaris, sshd will be listed by the command

```
$ ansible-galaxy search --galaxy-tags solaris,sshd
```

and installed locally

```
$ ansible-galaxy install <ROLE NAME>
```